# Raster merge in QGIS deletes scale

Tags: raster, merge, scale, qgis-3

I try to merge 2 raster tiffs in QGIS 3.10 (Raster-Miscellaneuous-Merge). The merge is executed but the resulting map is just black, the scale is set to 0, i.e. all the information of the rasters is gone. I attach screenshots of the configuration of the merge, the rasters before and after the merge and the log, to illustrate my problem.

What mistake have I made?

[image: rasters before merge]

[image: rasters after merge]

[image: merge specification]

[image: Log of the merge]

Comment: Go to raster properties - symbology and adjust contrast enhancement to stretch between min-max.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work out, the map remains black.

Comment: Are those eu_dem files public?

Comment: Yes they are, from the European Environment Agency: https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/copernicus-land-monitoring-service-eu-dem